# replacing numbers separated by single quotation marks ( ' ' ) using sed command

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to replace numbers using sed command in a file. Am able to replace the numbers but single quotations are missing. Please help me in completing this.

```
Command = sed -i 's/$my_id/'181122','98977','98934','9915','1748','9359','7959'/g' test.hql
Output = (181122,98977,98934,9915,1748,9359,7959)
```

Am trying to replace $my_id with those numbers in single quotations.

Comment: What's your sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Ricky Vijay, by seeing your profile came to know that you never select any answer as correct answer. Give it sometime and when few answers to your post are there select anyone of them as correct answer. You could do it for al your posts too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please change your `sed` to following once.

```
my_id="your_bash_value"
sed "s/$my_id/'181122','98977','98934','9915','1748','9359','7959'/g"  Input_file
```

Above is only helpful whe you want to use shell variable inside `sed`. Since OP's question was initially not clear so this was added.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you are not passing any variable and `$` is actually present in file then try following. Worked with GNU `sed`.

```
sed  "s/\\$/'181122','98977','98934','9915','1748','9359','7959'/g" Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Adding this one since OP says 2nd solution is NOT working for him.

```
sed 's/\$my_id/'"'"'181122'"'"','"'"'98977'"'"','"'"'98934'"'"','"'"'9915'"'"','"'"'1748'"'"','"'"'9359'"'"','"'"'7959'"'"'/g' Input_file
```

---

---

***4th Solution:*** OP told that 3rd solution worked for him but for 3rd solution if OP have n number of `'` values in his new value(which will be difficult to add `'"'"'` with all of them manually) which have `'` in their values then to generate this new value(which to be used in `sed` by code) try following.

Generate values which are acceptable by sed first here:

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v s2="\047" -v val="'181122','98977','98934','9915','1748','9359','7959'" 'BEGIN{value=s2 s1 s2 s1 s2;OFS=",";gsub(/\047/,value,val);print val}'
```

Above will change values from `'181122','98977','98934','9915','1748','9359','7959'` to `'"'"'181122'"'"','"'"'98977'"'"','"'"'98934'"'"','"'"'9915'"'"','"'"'1748'"'"','"'"'9359'"'"','"'"'7959'"'"'` Input variable value should be in same format which you posted. Then once you get it paste it in `sed` command and have the substitution.

Comment: ok let try this

Comment: @RickyVijay, sure, check my edit now and let me know?

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression --> Got this error

Comment: sed "s/$rms_id/'181122','98977','98934','9915','1748','9359','7959'/g" test1.hql

Comment: @RickyVijay. you should try my 2nd solution `sed  "s/\\$/'181122','98977','98934','9915','1748','9359','7959'/g" Input_file` and let me know?

Comment: 2nd solution also dint work. its just replacing numbers... not the (' ')

Comment: @RickyVijay, try 3rd one now? By the way 3 of them working fine for me, let me know?

Comment: What if i have more numbers how can i add so many qutations

Comment: @RickyVijay. please check 4th one?

Comment: that also dint work for me

Comment: @RickyVijay, you confirmed about 3rd right? Are you saying 4th one didn't work?

Comment: ya 4th also no luck

Comment: @RickyVijay, all of them worked for me, could you please check 1 thing `cat -v Input_file` once and see if you have control M characters in it, let me know then?

Comment: @RickyVijay, see this link my code is working fine here https://paiza.io/projects/SBBLCc3REy7LCIjBfCFePw?language=bash